# Spring Security users aren't getting roles

Tags: spring, spring-security

First of all, here's my Spring Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/getalltopics").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/createtopic").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/me").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/getcsrftoken").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://192.168.1.105:3000/", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("http://192.168.1.105:3000/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //This is the password encoder that I will be using
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Which leads me straight into my AccountDetailsService

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class AccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){
        Account account = accountService.findAccountByUsername(username);

        //TODO: Check if user exists

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(),
                account.isEnabled(), true, true, true,
                accountService.getAuthorities(account.getRoles()));
    }
}
```

Which again leads me into my accountService

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public Privilege findPrivilegeByName(String privilegeName){
        return privilegeRepository.findByName(privilegeName);
    }

    public void savePrivilege(Privilege privilege){
        privilegeRepository.save(privilege);
    }

    public Role findRoleByName(String roleName){
        return roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
    }

    public void saveRole(Role role){
        roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    public void saveAccount(Account account){
        accountRepository.save(account);
    }

    public Account findAccountByUsername(String username){
        return accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles){
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));
    }
    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles){
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Role role : roles){
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for(Privilege item : collection){
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }
    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String privilege : privileges){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

And here's my Account entity just in case it's necessary

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account extends TimeStampModel{
    // Extends TimeStampModel so we know when the user was created
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column
    private int amountOfLikes;

    @Column
    private int amountOfDislikes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> posts;

    private boolean isEnabled;

    private boolean isTokenExpired;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "account_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public Account(){}

    public Account(String username, String password, boolean isEnabled){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.amountOfDislikes = 0;
        this.amountOfLikes = 0;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

Now, my problem is that when I create a test user and give it the role ADMIN, and later on I try to check if the user has the role I always get returned false. If I try to make some requests to my server with the user, I always get 403 Forbidden. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my class where I set up a test user and this is the user that I use to try and log in

```
@Component
public class InitialDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    boolean alreadySetup = false;

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event){
        //don't do any setup if it has already been done
        if(alreadySetup) return;

        Privilege readPrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("READ_PRIVILEGE");
        Privilege writePrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("WRITE_PRIVILEGE");

        List<Privilege> adminPrivileges = Arrays.asList(readPrivilege, writePrivilege);
        List<Privilege> userPrivileges = Arrays.asList(readPrivilege);

        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_ADMIN", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USER", userPrivileges);

        Role adminRole = accountService.findRoleByName("ROLE_ADMIN");

        Account account = new Account("test", passwordEncoder.encode("123"), true);
        account.setRoles(Arrays.asList(adminRole));

        accountService.saveAccount(account);
        alreadySetup = true;
    }

    @Transactional
    Privilege createPrivilegeIfNotFound(String privilegeName){
        Privilege privilege = accountService.findPrivilegeByName(privilegeName);

        if(privilege == null){
            //if the privilege doesn't exist, we create one
            privilege = new Privilege(privilegeName);
            accountService.savePrivilege(privilege);
        }
        //if the privilege exists, just return it
        return privilege;
    }

    @Transactional
    Role createRoleIfNotFound(String roleName, Collection<Privilege> privilegeCollection){
        Role role = accountService.findRoleByName(roleName);

        if(role == null){
            //if the role doesn't exist, we create one
            role = new Role(roleName);
            role.setPrivileges(privilegeCollection);
            accountService.saveRole(role);
        }
        //if the role exists, just return it
        return role;
    }
}
```

Also I have this mapping set up which checks if user has some role, and they both return false always, if that helps.

```
    @GetMapping("/me")
    public Principal getMe(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper requestWrapper, Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(requestWrapper.isUserInRole("ADMIN"));
        System.out.println(requestWrapper.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        return principal;
    }
```

I just don't know what to do anymore, I'm so lost..

Comment: GrantedAuthorities for Roles are expected to be prefixed with ROLE_ , from the code shared it is not clear if you have already done that . https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-role-prefix

Comment: Try this once on WebSecurityConfig file : @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Comment: Roles look fine. Check if  in DB you have added password as encoded  BCryptPasswordEncoder..  Also please add server log to debug more..

Comment: @R.G Tried that, no luck

Comment: @DhwanilPatel also tried, nothing.

Comment: @MyTwoCents I don't have any logs? There are no errors or anything, I just get a 403 on my browser

Comment: @randomboiguyhere for trials , could you try disabling csrf to rule out anything going wrong there? http.csrf().disable()

Comment: @R.G Disabled CSRF, still same issue.

Comment: You are taking privileges from roles and converting them to GrantedAuthorities . I think that code is wrong . You need to create GrantedAuthorities from the role.

Comment: @R.G Could you elaborate a bit more? Are you saying that my GrantedAuthorities should just be my Roles?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-granted-authority , please go through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205420/discussion-between-r-g-and-randomboiguyhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitialDataLoader.createRoleIfNotFound()` creates Roles with privileges `READ_PRIVILEGE` and `WRITE_PRIVILEGE`

`AccountService.getGrantedAuthorities()` builds the `SimpleGrantedAuthority` objects based on the privileges and not for the Role ADMIN.

This prevents the Authorization to work as expected. Creating `SimpleGrantedAuthority` objects with the required role should fix the Authorization issue here.

Comment: Yup, changing the SimpleGrantedAuthority to Roles resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I think first of all you should put **@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)** on top of **SecurityConfig**  class.

And be careful when you are using 
**.antMatchers("/api/getalltopics").hasRole("ADMIN")**  here. I used like this
**.antMatchers("/api/getalltopics").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")**. Just change *hasRole* with *hasAnyRole*. In addition in database user`s authority should be written like this: **"ROLE_ADMIN"** or  **"ROLE_USER"**. I used like above and it worked well.

If you saved user`s password in hashed form inside database then you should modify piece of your code below

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

Additionally, If you are creating custom login page then you should write like below, it works fine in my code

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/add_friends").hasAnyRole( "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/submit_info").hasAnyRole( "ADMIN")
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successForwardUrl("/welcome_page")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

**/login** is the jsp file,  and **/welcome_page** is controller method. Maybe your login and password is not going to database even. Check that out.

Comment: I tried all of the things that you listed, nothing seems to have helped. I have also added my initial setup to the original post so you can check that out

Comment: My login is successful because I have a exposed api call "/me" which returns my Principal, so I know that the login works. But when I try making a call to the backend api from my frontend, I get a 403. Even If I try making a request straight through localhost:8080(my server port) it still gives me a 403. I've also added the /me call to my post, check it out.